# groupby with orm nodejs on postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-orm2

Hallo i have a problem to select groupBy in nodejs with ORM(node-orm2) and databse postgresql.

code :

```
req.models.roomcategorylog.find(["id", "Z"],
function(err, results) {
if (err) {
    res.json({
        status: false,
        message: 'Error found',
        data:err
    });
} else {
    res.json({
        status:true,
        message: 'Data found',
        data:results
    });
    // console.log(results);
}
});
```

this code have result like this :

```
id , users_id , username
37  1          faris
36  1          faris
35  1          faris
34  2          ridho
33  3          kotaro
```

but what i need in my sistem i want 1 "users_id" like group by in query with result :

```
id , users_id , username
37  1          faris
34  2          ridho
33  3          kotaro
```

thanks for your attention and solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like this:

```
req.models.roomcategorylog
    .aggregate(["username", "users_id"], { id: "Z" })
    .groupBy("username").get(function(err, results) {
         // results should be your grouped data
    })
```

Comment: how can i get aggregate ? in my result said " Invalid error code: Missing aggregate functions " . thx before